# How to configure MUI X's DateRangePicker to select weekly ranges?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x, mui-x-date-picker

I'm using the DateRangePicker component from MUI X in my React application. I want to configure it such that users can only select date ranges that represent a full week (i.e., from Monday to Sunday).

Here's the basic setup I have:

```
import { DateRangePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers-pro/DateRangePicker';


<DateRangePicker localeText={{ start: 'Check-in', end: 'Check-out' }} />
```

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vnvpdw?file=/Demo.js:478-559)

How can I modify the DateRangePicker to enforce the selection of only weekly ranges? Ideally, if a user selects a date, the component should auto-fill the range to the corresponding week. Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The best you can do with a `DateRangePicker` is use validation to show validation error and ask user to select a week. If that's not good enough, I'd say use a date picker instead of a date range picker, after user selects a date, use the start of week and end of week to mark the week and keep it in a separate state than the controlled state of date picker while customizing the `day` slot to show the whole week selected in the UI.